# Google Drive: "The download quota for this file has been exceeded"

Tags: html, google-drive

Quiero crear un `<video>` a partir del enlace a un video mio en Google Drive, probé con lo que hay en internet y encuentro el siguiente metodo:

```
<video controls>
    <source src="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[fileID]?alt=media&key=[keyID]" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Solo al principio el método sí que funcionaba, pero después de varias reproducciones de prueba, el enlace dejó de funcionar; ingresé el enlace directamente al navegador, y me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!

Eso es algo completamente normal y, por desgracia, inevitable con las descargas desde Google Drive. Con el tiempo ese error dejará de dar, pero si haces varias pruebas y vuelves a descargarlo varias veces al final Google Drive te lo impide, tras demasiados intentos y lanza ese error.
A mi me ha pasado varias veces y la única forma de solucionarlo es esperar (o copiártelo a tu propia unidad desde otra cuenta y probar las descargas desde ahí).
Ya lo siento no haber podido solucionar el problema, pero es algo inevitable.

¡Saludos!